# Zero divisors within the ring of dual numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $\mathbb{R}(\epsilon) = \{ a + b \epsilon : a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}, $ where $(a + b\epsilon) + (c + d\epsilon) = (a+c) + (b+d)\epsilon$ and $(a+ b\epsilon) \cdot (c + d\epsilon) = ac + (ad + bc)\epsilon$, where $\epsilon^2 = 0.$

I am asked to show the following:

Show that $a + b\epsilon$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{R}(\epsilon)$ if and only if $a=0$.

Here is my attempt:

$\implies)$  Suppose that $a+b\epsilon$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{R}(\epsilon).$  Then for $c+d\epsilon \neq 0$ we have $(a + b\epsilon)(c+d\epsilon) = ac + (ad + bc)\epsilon =0.$

If we multiply both sides of the last equation by $\epsilon$ on the right, we get

$[ac + (ad + bc)]\epsilon = 0\cdot\epsilon$, which gives us

$ac\epsilon + (ad + bc)\epsilon^2 = 0$, since $\epsilon^2 = 0$ we get that

$ac\epsilon = 0$ which happens when $a=0.$

For the other direction I am kind of stuck on how to begin.  Assuming that $a=0$ doesn't seem to help.  Should I try this direction by contraposition?

Comment: You did the hard part, the other direction is asking "is $b\epsilon$ a zero divisor?" which it clearly is; just square it.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $a=0$, consider $(b\epsilon)^2=0$.
- If $a \neq 0$, consider $(a+b\epsilon)(a-b\epsilon)=a^2 \in \mathbb
     R^*$.